# Graphing distribution of independent variable for any given dataset

Tags: r, data-mining

I am looking to automate the process of exploratory data analysis and would like to graph the distribution (using line plots, histograms, density curves, etc.) of all the input variables. As my code stands, I am simply getting 4 blank graphics windows. What am I doing incorrectly? If there is a better approach, I am open to that as well.

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

for (i in names(mydata)){
    qplot(data=mydata,i,geom="bar", fill="admit")
    dev.new()
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `kohonen` package for something similar.

Comment: This situation looks like one where `aes_string` might come in handy (you'll also need `print`).  I found an example of someone in a very similar situation [here](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/rggplot2-tip-aes_string/).

Comment: aosmith, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Since this is my first post, how do I go about acknowledging that you have correctly answered my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation looks like one where `aes_string` would come in handy (along with the addition of `print` around your call to `ggplot`).  I found [this post](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/rggplot2-tip-aes_string/) showing how to use `aes_string` with `ggplot` inside a loop.

So it would look something like this:

```
mydata$admit = factor(mydata$admit)
for(i in names(mydata)) {
  print(ggplot(mydata) + geom_bar(aes_string(x = i, fill = "admit")))
}
```

I'm working in RStudio so have skipped the `dev.new` part of your code.  I found I needed to convert `admit` to a factor, as well.